# I can't change the product thumbnail programmatically

Tags: magento2, product-images

Somehow I am unable to change the thumbnail of an Product and it drives me crazy.

**Setup**

```
$product = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
    ->setStoreIds([0,1,$this->store_other_website->getId()])
    ->setWebsiteIds([1,$this->website->getId()])
    ->setDescription('Store description')
    ->setName("testproduct") // Use default
    ->setPrice("99.99") // Store price
    ->setSku("TEST-1") // Store price
    ->setVisibility(null) // Use default
    ->setCountryOfManufacture(null) // Use default
    ->setImage('/m/a/magento_image1.jpg')
    ->setSmallImage('/m/a/magento_image1.jpg')
    ->setThumbnail('/m/a/magento_image1.jpg')
    ->setData(
        'media_gallery',
        [
            'images' => [
                [
                    'file' => '/m/a/magento_image.jpg',
                    'position' => 1,
                    'label' => 'Image Alt Text 1',
                    'disabled' => 0,
                    'media_type' => 'image'
                ],
            ]
        ]
    )
    ->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true)
    ->save();

$imagePath = "new_image.jpg"; // path of the image
$mediaGalleryProcessor = $this->objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor::class);
$mediaGalleryProcessor->addImage($product, $imagePath, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), true, false);
```

**What should work**

```
$thumbnail = "/n/e/new_image.jpg";
$product->setThumbnail($thumbnail);
$product->save();
$product->getData('thumbnail') // = "/n/e/new_image.jpg"
```

**What actually happens**

```
$thumbnail = "/n/e/new_image.jpg";
$product->setThumbnail($thumbnail);
$product->save();
$product->getData('thumbnail') // = "/m/a/magento_image1.jpg"
```

as soon as i save the product the thumbnail gets reverted to the old one.